# hide salt value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there away to hide the salt value in python? i have use the code below to generates salt value 32 bit to add it into data after encoding to binary. and to retrieve the data will be subtract the encoding noise with data

```
import secrets
salt = secrets.token_hex(32)
name = 'natalie'
```

suppose the `salt=29638f0807ac8e461a66d9aeb6ef990bc7be54a7ca37f1a35966436bfe65bcf3` and i have encode and decode the data with salt, my question is there a way to hide this salt value? because its important to me to retrieve the original data from it later. i'm using spyder python 3.6.4

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"?

Comment: what i mean is secure the salt value, because after encoding the data with salt i will store in database, and i have another method to select the data and subtract with salt value. so my point is how to secure that salt value?? i dont want it to insert into database . hope you got my point

Comment: I'm not sure how you're expecting to keep something to subtract later if you don't store it _somewhere_

Comment: if you have a value that can encode and decode all your private data i would not save it in the database itself! you can use an env file for safe keeping of the salt string or secret code. You can retrieve anything from env file with `os.environ.get(key name)`

Comment: @ Linh Nguyen yes thats why i dont want to save it into database. what i did is chunks the slat into 8 bits as i have 4 attribute and adding these 8 bit into these attribute and store in database, and later collect these 8bit chunks to back as salt value. is  this os.environ.get(key name) will be work for different salt every time? how to link it with data from database? thank you

Comment: @rdas thats what i'm trying to do, i need way to hide/secure the salt value

Comment: purpose of `.env` file is to store secure data like api keys, secret key,... between collabs , so how many layer of encrypt you got you will always got a key and saving it in database is 100% not recommend

Comment: for example you set secret_key = 123456abc then you can access in your code with os.environ.get("secret_key") , your point of getting it from data is no different from getting it from env file, the catch is if there an sql inject attack they will be able to query your data for the key and decode everything

Comment: @Linh Nguyen could you give clear example to run i got confused im searching now about what u said , i dont know from where to start. thank you sir,

Comment: As I understand the problem, salt is not meant to be hidden. It just needs to be added to prevent compromisation in the case if two passwords are identical.

Comment: @ ged not just for password, im using salt to obfuscation the data, to add salt value into original data by encoding and decoding it and later subtract it.

Comment: What you're describing is pepper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)

Comment: @  Alex Hall, thanks for reply , it's kind of of that but the above link use hash password value by match the salt and input data,in my case i dont use hash also there is no input data. im direct select data from database 1 and encode data with random salt and insert into database 2 and later select from database 2 and subtract data with the salt that use in encoding. thank you again for the link